Show empty varchar if a Date is null and show just the year part if it is not null
I am showing Year from a Date, but when it is null, it should show empty string or varchar values if it is not null, it should display me just the year part, it doesn't have to be only integer, but I need to show this way, any help greatly appreciated, I tried it below way but I was able to get year part but for the null values, it is taking 0 or 1900 like this, any help please, I am using SQL Server.
cast(format(tForm.CreatedDate, 'yyyy') as int) 'FormCreatedDate'



You'll need to decide if you want an INT or a VARCHAR.   There is no "empty" INT.

That said.  isnull(datename(year,Form.CreatedDate),'')

or even  concat('',datename(year,Form.CreatedDate))

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Datename will perform better than format

Another approach is to just use YEAR(Form.CreatedDate) to return the year number and let your presentation layer display any null values as an empty string.

(Optional) Set old versions for testing
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

Use TRY_CAST to get real dates and cast for varchar if invalid
declare @CorrectDate datetime = getdate();

declare @WrongDate varchar(max) = '150-01-01';
/*or*/
declare @WrongDate date = null;

declare @ExceptDate varchar(max) = 'can br any type, not date';


SELECT YEAR(@CorrectDate) as Correct_Date
      ,ISNULL(CAST(YEAR(TRY_CAST(@WrongDate as date)) AS VARCHAR),'') as Empty_DATA
      ,YEAR(TRY_CAST(@ExceptDate as date)) as Except_Date

db<>fiddle

(From John Cappelletti's comment above.)
You can use the expression: isnull(datename(year,Form.CreatedDate),'').
Sample results:



CreatedDate
YearText




1969-07-20 20:17:40
1969


2024-12-06 22:43:06
2024


null




See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
